# fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals openssl : ssleay32MD.lib,libeay32MD.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, openssl, unresolved-external

I am new to Openssl, and trying to run a dhclient program available online at http://www.josuegomes.com/codeblog/dhclient.htm.

While doing so I get following errors,

> dhclient.cpp
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_print_errors_fp referenced in function "void __cdecl handle_error(char const *,int,char const *)" (?handle_error@@YAXPBDH0@Z)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function "void __cdecl init_OpenSSL(void)" (?init_OpenSSL@@YAXXZ)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_library_init referenced in function "void __cdecl init_OpenSSL(void)" (?init_OpenSSL@@YAXXZ)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list referenced in function "struct ssl_ctx_st * __cdecl setup_ctx(void)" (?setup_ctx@@YAPAUssl_ctx_st@@XZ)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_new referenced in function "struct ssl_ctx_st * __cdecl setup_ctx(void)" (?setup_ctx@@YAPAUssl_ctx_st@@XZ)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TLSv1_client_method referenced in function "struct ssl_ctx_st * __cdecl setup_ctx(void)" (?setup_ctx@@YAPAUssl_ctx_st@@XZ)
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_free referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_shutdown referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_read referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_write referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_connect referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_set_bio referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_new referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_ctrl referenced in function _main
>   1>dhclient.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BIO_new_connect referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Users\Rucha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\emptyprojectssl\Debug\emptyprojectssl.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals

I have added includes and library paths, also my runtime library is MD and I have added ssleay32MD.lib
libeay32MD.lib to external dependencies.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  When compiling the OpenSSL libraries I had to make sure that they compiled with the right Visual Studio SDK and the right Platform.  Then ensuring they are in the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and i solved.
Try to look if you are using the right libraries, i mean if you are using x64 lib and compiling with 32-bit then it will through the same error.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I think the debug libs are `ssleay32MDd.lib` and `libeay32MDd.lib` (note the "d" suffix).

Comment: Thanks Fraser, I tired playin with all possible combinations but m still getting the same errors!